# How to save select gender with Radio Button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button

I have 2 RadioButtons with options Male and Female. I want to save string value to database as per the radio button selection, and this my code:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage="please select your gender")]
public string JenisKelamin { get; set; }
```

Markup:

```
<div>
    @Html.Label("Jenis Kelamin")
    @Html.RadioButton("rbGrp", "MALE", isChecked :true) @Html.Label("MALE")
    @Html.RadioButton("rbGrp", "FEMALE", isChecked :false) @Html.Label("FEMALE")
</div>
```

If the first RadioButton is selected, then save string MALE to database, otherwise FEMALE.

Comment: The [tag:model-view-controller] tag is intended for questions about the *pattern*, not the specific ASP.NET implementation. I've adjusted your tag; please remember to use the correct one in the future.

Comment: are u have the article or pattern abaout RadioButton MVC

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for tutorial recommendations (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You need to show what you've tried so far, and then someone can help you when you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RadioButtonFor html helper here and post form directly. Bind your model property to it. That's how it works.

For example :

```
@RadioButtonFor(model=> model.JenisKelamin, "Male", new { @checked = true} )
@RadioButtonFor(model=> model.JenisKelamin, "Female", new { @checked = false} )
```

Put them inside form and submit form using submit button. At controller side accept your model and MVC do work for you.

Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery selector to do it:

Simply by this code below:

```
$("input[id=rbGrp]:radio").change(function () {

   var radiovalue= $("#rbGrp:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + "YourController/SaveMethod",
    data: {
        selection: radioValue
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

In your MVC Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveMethod(string selection)
{
    // do something
    var success = true; // your method
    return Json(new {result = success ? "ok" : "error" });
}
```